# React.js: Updating an Array of Objects stored in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have an Array of Objects that I'm storing in state with each Object storing values I want to then use to render components:

```
const activeModal = [
    { modalName: 'dashboard', modal: Dashboard, active: true, icon: DashboardIcon, iconColor: 'black', iconBackground: 'white' },
    { modalName: 'memsline', modal: MEMsLine, active: false, icon: MEMsLineIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'mems', modal: MEMsGrid, active: false, icon: MEMsIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'events', modal: Events, active: false, icon: EventIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'people', modal: People, active: false, icon: PeopleIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'places', modal: Places, active: false, icon: PlaceIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'music', modal: Music, active: false, icon: MusicIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'movies', modal: Movies, active: false, icon: MovieIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'tvshows', modal: TVShows, active: false, icon: TVIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'games', modal: Games, active: false, icon: GameIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' },
    { modalName: 'settings', modal: UserSettings, active: false, icon: SettingsIcon, iconColor: 'white', iconBackground: 'black' }
]
```

I am trying to write a function that updates the Array of Objects when a button is clicked. I have the button set up to call the function `openModal` `onClick` and pass back the `modalName` as follows:

```
openModal = modalType => () => {
    this.setState(state => {
        const updatedActiveModal = state.activeModal.map(item => {
            if (item.active === true) {
                return {
                    modalName: item.modalName,
                    modal: item.modal,
                    active: false,
                    icon: item.icon,
                    iconColor: 'white',
                    iconBackground: 'black'
                };
            } else if (item.modalName === modalType) {
                return {
                    modalName: item.modalName,
                    modal: item.modal,
                    active: true,
                    icon: item.icon,
                    iconColor: 'black',
                    iconBackground: 'white'
                };
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        });
        return {
            updatedActiveModal,
        };
    });
};
```

However, when I click the button nothing is happening. What I would expect to happen is that the  `activeModal` Array of Objects is updated to change the modal that is currently active's `active` value to `false`, the `iconColor` to `'white'` and the `backgroundColor` to `'black'`. It should also change the `active` value of the modal that was clicked on from `false` to `true`, the `iconColor` to `'black'` and the `backgroundColor` to `'white'` and save all the changes to `state`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong as the code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to change:

```
return {
    updatedActiveModal,
};
```

to

```
return {
    activeModal: updatedActiveModal,
};
```

Comment: Yep, you're right - I was so close! Thank you. Can you explain why `activeModal:` is needed so I can learn why it's required?

Comment: when you do `return {
    updatedActiveModal,
};` it's equivalent to `return {
    updatedActiveModal: updatedActiveModal,
};`, so your state would then have `{activeModal /* old value */, updatedActiveModel /* new value */ }`, but elsewhere in your code you only look at `state.activeModal`, so you need to tell state to replace your `activeModel` with your `updatedActiveModal`, not add a new key/value pair to state.